# ReactJs : How to send function as prop in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anybody tell me how i send function in loop i got error if i send it directly to loop. is there anyway to send function in loop and call it from the function

i have CommentListItem.js in which i calling SubCommentListItem

```
<SubCommentListItem 
                            key={subcomment.id} 
                            data={subcomment} 
                            parentid={commentID} 
                            updateComment={(comment) => this.updateComment()}
                            user={user} postid={postid} 
                            />
```

and in SubCommentListItem i m calling form component

```
            {this.state.showForm ? (<CommentForm updateComment={this.updateComment} class={'subCommentFormBox'} parentid={this.state.parentid} postid={postid} user={user} />):(<div></div>)}
```

here is updateComment Function but its not updating prop of CommentListITem

```
updateComment(comment) {
        this.setState({showForm:false})
        this.props.updateComment(comment)
    }
```

Comment: Want to props function so i can call it back

Comment: There's two ways (well several, but here are two ways), you should make the function a lambda, i.e. replace "function (subcomment, i)" with "(subcomment, i) =>", else "this" will refer to this.state.subcomments, or you can replace "function (subcomment, i)" with "function (subcomment, i, subcomments)" and replace "this.state.subcomments" with "subcomments", maps third argument is the array itself.

Comment: For completeness let me add that another way to do it is to define a method in your class, commentsMap(subcomment, i) ... and then in your constructor do this.commentsMap = this.commentsMap.bind(this), then the "this" will always refer to the instance of the class you have made and you can do "this.state.subcomments.map(this.commentMap)"

Comment: no its not work in that way

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: is there any way i share my files ?

Comment: I don't think this will be needed. You can edit your question and print the error you are getting in it. You can also add relevant code and a more in-depth explanation of your problem.

Comment: i added please check

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to make a few changes to your code.

First, the update function. Let's make it into an arrow function so you don't have to `bind` it :

```
updateComment = comment => {
    this.setState({ showForm:false })
    this.props.updateComment(comment)
}
```

Now simply send the reference to it in your props :

```
<SubCommentListItem
    key={subcomment.id}
    data={subcomment}
    parentid={commentID}
    updateComment={props.updateComment}
    user={user} postid={postid}
/>
```

And here is how you can call it inside `SubCommentListItem` :

```
this.props.updateComment(yourComment)
```

This syntax is the same as the one in it's parent component

Also, the following code :

```
{this.state.showForm ? (<CommentForm updateComment={this.updateComment} class={'subCommentFormBox'} parentid={this.state.parentid} postid={postid} user={user} />):(<div></div>)}
```

Can be shortened to this :

```
{this.state.showForm && <CommentForm updateComment={this.updateComment} class='subCommentFormBox' parentid={this.state.parentid} postid={postid} user={user} />}
```

And I would recommend using `className` in React instead of `class`

Comment: it saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateComment' of undefined

Comment: This means `this.props` is undefined, can you show me the component using it (by editing your question)

Comment: check this image
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3860951/a556f745f128bfef64206a35714afefe

Comment: Lol, `this` is undefined... interesting. Show me the full class code

Comment: Nervermind, you used a stateless component and forgot to tell us. Just use `props.updateComment` and make sure you are receiving your `props` variable in your function

Comment: Like the following : `const SubCommentListItem = props => { /* your logic */ }`

Comment: i fix that problem now problems is in SubCommentListItem.js

Comment: when it call this function 
 updateComment(comment) {
        this.setState({showForm:false})
        this.props.updateComment(comment)
    }

Comment: everything working fine now problem is SUbCommentListitem.js

updateComment(comment) {
        this.setState({showForm:false})
        //this.props.updateComment(comment)
        console.log(comment)
    }

Comment: if i set state and call props also it not work but i do only one thing its work whats problem

Comment: I'm going to need to see your class declaration, you should edit your answer with it and just remove the functions that are not relevant to your problem..

Comment: you get its wrong

if your answer you thing updateComment is props function in CommentListItem.js which i passing to SubCommentListItem 

but updateComment is CommentListItem.js function 
so when i use 
`<SubCommentListItem
    key={subcomment.id}
    data={subcomment}
    parentid={commentID}
    updateComment={this.updateComment}
    user={user} postid={postid}
/> `
its not work fine i think now you can help me

Comment: i solved it with better way thanks you help me aloot i get your point

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{this.state.subcomments.map(function (subcomment, i) {
      return (
              <SubCommentListItem key={subcomment.id} 
                subcomment= {this.state.subcomments} 
                data={subcomment} parentid={commentID} 
                user={user} postid={postid}
                yourfunctionname={() => this.props.yourfunction()}
               />
              );
 })}
```

Comment: i receive this error
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in commentForm (at subCommentListItem.js:58)